# show results for a view with certain node reference

Tags: views, nodes

I have created two content types a home and a subdivision.  I have added a subdivision reference field in the home content type.

What i want to have is in each subdivision page, show a teaser of the homes that reference that particular subdivision.  I imagine that would be done using views, but I am not sure.

Any help on how to create this view block on the subdivision node would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is what views is particularly good at, in my opinion. You should be able to get started by creating a subdivision page view. Then you should be able to create a relationship based on the reference field. This would give you access to sort based upon whether the home appeared in that subdivision.